# c# stop controls being added to containers through designer

Tags: c#, controls, containers

I am currently working on a program that uses multiple panels to split up the various fields on the Form. They cover 100% of the form's viewable area.

However, there are items I want to add that are above the structure of the Form, so that they will not be contained by a panel. How can I add a control to an area of the form without it being added to a panel that is occupying the same area?

To clarify, when I drag a TextBox or other control over a panel, it gets automatically added to it's list of controls, which I do not want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the form, then double-click the control in the toolbox.
This will add it to the selected container.

You will probably then want to set `Dock` to Top, and perhaps send to back.

Comment: What about when I need to move the control? Do I still have to use the arrow keys to move it (incredibly slowly) around?

Comment: @Chris: You could set the `Location` property in the Properties grid.  Alternatively, temporarily undock the main panel.

Comment: Ah, didn't think about moving the main panel, and then resetting it's position. I think I may also work on creating a panel that can shrink with a property, and then restore it afterwards.